# How to make HTML element that is manually drawn stay fixed?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to manually draw a rectangle in HTML using dashes and special characters (-, +, *) like this:

```
<div>
<pre>
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                                |
|                                                                                |
|                                                                                |
|                                                                                |
|                                                                                |
|                                                                                |
|                                                                                |
|                                                                                |
|                                                                                |
|                                                                                |
|                                                                                |
|                                                                                |
|                                                                                |
|                                                                                |
|                                                                                |
|                                                                                |
|                                                                                |
|                                                                                |
|                                                                                |
|                                                                                |
|                                                                                |
|                                                                                |
|                                                                                |
|                                                                                |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
</pre>
</a>
</div>
```

I also plan on putting text and other elements inside the rectangle, but if I do that, the rectangle would look wonky:

```
<div>
<a href="HOME.HTM" id="coc">
<pre>
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                                |
|                                                                                |
|                                                                                |
|                                                                                |
|                                                                                |
|                                                                                |
|                                                                                |
|                                                                                |
|                                                                                |
|                                                                                |
|                                                                                |
|                                                                                |
|                                                                                |
|                                                                                |
|                                                                                |
|                                                                                |
|                                                                                |
|                                                                                |
|                                                                                |
|                                                                                |
|                                                                                |
|                                                                                |
|                                                                                |
|             random text to put inside                                                                   |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
</pre>
</a>
</div>
```

Which would be rendered on the screen as something like this: [image: See how the vertical elements no longer align]

How would I force the HTML to align properly and maintain the rectangular shape that's drawn even with text elements inside?

Comment: Why not just remove the now-extraneous whitespaces yourself in your markup...? Am I missing something?

Comment: Obviously I could remove the whitespace, but I was wondering if there is a more effective way of doing this in html.

Comment: I'd use a multidimensional array. write some poke functions to push whatever into each cell, and render, essentially it's just a grid.

Answer (score 0):

You can use two separate elements and align them using relative positioning:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="box">
+---+
|   |
|   |
|   |
+---+
    </div>
    <div class="text">
 
 some text
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    position: relative;
}

.box {
    white-space: pre;
    font-family: monospace;
}

.text {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    white-space: pre;
    font-family: monospace;
}
```

Final result:
[image: final result]

Comment: I tried copying your code but the text sticks out: https://codepen.io/tetrahed432/pen/wvpOzBR

Comment: yeah that was a typo. i updated the code: `className` should be `class`

Answer (score 0):

I would just use a [border-image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-image). Lets say you got this image that is 210x210 pixels with a grid consisting of nine squares each with a size of 70x70 pixels.

[image]

Just mess around with `border-image-slice` and `border-width` to get something that is good enough.

And don't use `pre`. Just style it to look like a monochrome screen.

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  color: limegreen;
  font-family: "Courier New";
}

.ascii-border {
  --vertical-slice: 60;
  --horizontal-slice: 70;
  height: 300px;
  width: 400px;
  padding: 1rem;
  border: 4px double currentColor;
  border-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/9aAyn.png);
  border-image-slice: var(--vertical-slice) var(--horizontal-slice);
  border-width: 20px;
  border-image-repeat: round;
}
```

```html
<div class="ascii-border">
  Hello world
</div>
```